# Calling phone from Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I can make phone calls from Outlook 2010, but only from the full contact page. If I receive an email from an existing contact, I right-click on the name and the phone symbol is grayed out. So I have to click on "Lookup contact" and call from there... is there a way to enable calling directly from the received email?

Thanks